# Redshift : recursive update for stores or product

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to do a recursive update taking into account which was the oldest store and for all the stores that it has been until reaching the last one.

an example of the table

| store_initial | store_prev | store_end | openning_date | closing_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 230 |  | 230 | 22/01/2016 | 31/06/2018 |
| 608 | 230 | 608 | 01/07/2018 | 01/08/2022 |
| 717 | 608 | 717 | 01/08/2022 | null |

and this is what i expect

| store_initial | store_prev | store_end | openning_date | closing_date | store_LFL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 230 |  | 230 | 22/01/2016 | 31/06/2018 | 717 |
| 608 | 230 | 608 | 01/07/2018 | 01/08/2022 | 717 |
| 717 | 608 | 717 | 01/08/2022 | null | 717 |

I am doing in redshift. can someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You hit the nail on the head - you need a recursive process.  Redshift has recursive CTEs which can perform this unrolling for you.

First off you should provide your data in an "insert values" format so others can more easily help you.  Like this:

```
create table test (
store_initial int,
store_prev int,
store_end int,
openning_date date,
closing_date date);

insert into test values 
(230, null, 230, '2016/01/22', '2018/06/30'),
(608, 230,  608, '2018/07/01', '2022/08/01'),
(717, 608,  717, '2022/08/01', null);
```

Now for the meat.  Recursive CTEs are a powerful tool and you can read up on them at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

This is a way to use them to perform the function you desire on your test data:

```
with recursive chain(store_initial, store_prev, store_end, openning_date, closing_date, store_lfl, n) as (
select store_initial, store_prev, store_end, openning_date, closing_date, store_initial as store_lfl, 1 as n
from test 
union all
select a.store_initial, a.store_prev, a.store_end, a.openning_date, a.closing_date, nvl(b.store_initial, a.store_lfl), n + 1
from chain a
left join test b
on a.store_lfl = b.store_prev
where b.store_initial is not null
),
maxn as (
select store_initial, max(n) as maxn 
from chain
group by store_initial
)
select c.store_initial, store_prev, store_end, openning_date, closing_date, store_lfl
from chain c
join maxn m
on c.n = m.maxn and c.store_initial = m.store_initial
order by store_initial;
```

The first CTE (chain) is recursive an walks the table repeatedly until it cannot go any deeper.  This produces one row for each store for each level of the walk.

Next it find the max depth for each store (maxn).

Finally is joins these to fine the row from chain with the max depth.

Comment: It works...thank you very much.
I also take this opportunity to thank you for the tips on how to give the information so that you can help me better.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's my time to give back to the community that helped me.